# laravel , кнопка вернутся на предыдущую страницу

Tags: javascript, laravel

есть страница в админке с списком новостей с пагинацией типо: 
*/dashboard/news?page=10*
можно перейти на страницу редактирования :
*/dashboard/news/edit/412*
на странице редактирования должна быть кнопка вернутся на предыдущую страницу(сейчас она работает на history) список, но если я сохраняю изменения новости то страница обновляется и предыдущая страницу уже не список а та что содержит необновленные данные новости, необходимо пропускать такие моменты потому что новость может быть сохранена несколько раз и потом нажимать на кнопку назад нужно несколько раз подскажите как куда копать , уже весь гугл перерыл

Answer (score 1):

Установите для ссылки вашей кнопки вернуться назад тот роут который вам необходим, тогда будет всё равно сколько раз вы сохраните страницу

Comment: да как вариант , так изначально было сделано но тогда мы возвращаемся к первой странице нужного списка а редактируемая запись может находтся на 500 странице из 1000 , страниц уже около 1040 вывод по 10 записей

Comment: @No_Name как вариант, к ссылке на редактирование передавать дополнительный параметр номера страницы, и потом класть его в кнопку вернуться назад

Comment: звучит логично , буду так делать наверно , спасибо